# Difference between connection.close and connection.dispose using Asp.net Connection String?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Difference between connection.close and connection.dispose using Asp.net Connection String ?
for ex:

```
Globals.dr.Dispose(); 
Globals.dr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispose() automatically calls .Close for SqlConnection. So you can only call Dispose or better use the using statement in C#.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection()...)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: @NadeemAfana-Thank u lot

Comment: @NadeemAfana- i have tried function in 2 redaers at the time of im getting this error" invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed" ? Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

When using `Dispose()` it automatically calls the `Close()` method on the `Connection` object

Comment: @AppDeveloper-Thank u lot

Answer (score 0):

Close actually closes the open connection to database. but dispose will remove the connection object from memory.
since sqlconnection implements Finalize/Dispose pattern if you dispose connection before closing it, then close method is automaticly called.

[Sql connection close method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

basically dispose is about memory and close is about connection :D

Comment: @Hassan-Thank u lot and lots

Comment: @Hassan-i have tried function in 2 redaers at the time of im getting this error" invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed" ? Thank in advance

Comment: take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455963/getting-invalid-attempt-to-call-read-when-reader-is-closed