# c# wpf; sqldatareader invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi everyone I have a application on c# wpf . I' am trying to call data then update it, but i get this error "invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed". I don't know where is the problem

I am using this code:

```
        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server = localhost; database= test;Integrated Security = true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id, name, quantity from so where name like '%" + txt.Text + "%'", con);
       SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rd.Read())
            if (Convert.ToInt32(rd["quantity"]) > 0)
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "Update so set quantity =quantity - 1  where name Like '%' + @name + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("sorry!");

        }
       rd.Close();
        con.Close();


    }
```

Comment: You are closing reader in the loop with `rd.Close()` and later on trying to read from it. Also, you have enabled the sql injection.

Comment: Add  rd.Close(); before con.close();  Datareader is closed before query execute.

Comment: I tried also to put the rd. close under con.Close but aslo get this error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Comment: @Irfan - Incorrect, he should move `rd.Close()` on the line before `con.Close()`

Comment: @Dusan I just tried but I am getting this error " There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first".

Comment: @Irfan still the same "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"

Comment: Then you should create new command and not reuse the one that is already used by the reader.

Comment: Dusan How to do because i am new at c#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455963/getting-invalid-attempt-to-call-read-when-reader-is-closed)

Comment: DalmTo ive read this article, it didnt help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the reader within the while loop of rd.Read(). Thus, when the while loop continues after closing it, the reader throws an exception since it's closed when you try reading it.

Try this?

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server = localhost; database= test;Integrated Security = true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand("select id, name, quantity from so where name like '%" + txt.Text + "%'", con);
    SqlDataReader rd = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(rd["quantity"]) > 0)
        {
            SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("Update so set quantity =quantity - 1  where name Like '%' + @name + '%'", con);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt.Text);
            updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("sorry!");
        }
    }

    rd.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: it isnt working  still getting this "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Comment: As said above, because you already used that command earlier, it won't work anymore. I updated the code to use a second command for the update query.